How to concatenate files included in files containing names of files
I have 4 txt files containing an ordered collection of names of files
e.g
file L001 contains file1_L001 file2_L001 file3_L001 .. and so on (48 files), each in a new lane
file L002 contains file1_L002 file2_L002 file3_L002 .. and so on (48 files as well)
file L003 contains file1_L003 file2_L003 file3_L003 .. and so on (48 files as well)
file L004 contains file1_L004 file2_L004 file3_L004 .. and son on with up to 48 file names
What I want is to concatenate, creating new files using bash, something like
cat file1_L001 file1_L002 file1_L003 file1_L004 > All_file1.file
cat file2_L001 file2_L002 file2_L003 file2_L004 > All_file2.file
...
cat file48_L001 file48_L002 file48_L003 file48_L004 > All_file48.file

That is, to repeat the same process with file2_L001 file2_L002 file2_L003 file2_L004 and so on up to file48
My problem is that I unknow how to call a specific file in order included into the file of names. I can get those names with a cat command, but I don't know how to select one determined of these files to apply, for example, a nested series of for

Please [edit] your question to show us a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output that we can copy/paste as-is to test with. Right now I can image a few different things your textual description might mean.

I need to limit the cat operation is such way that only the first files of the 4 files of names are concatenated together. Then, only the second files in each of the 4 files with names, then only the third files and so on with the 48 files included in each of the 4 files containing the names
e.g
L001  L002  L003  L004  (these are the files with the names of files)
file1   file1   file1   file1  (these are the names of the files I want to concatenate
file2   file2   file2   file2  (these again, with a name such as All_files2
......

I can do the nested loop, but I don't know how to access to the files included in the file of names in order
If I run cat, all 48 files appear
¿How can I select only the 4 first ones?, Then the 4 seconds, and so on

The solution is using awk. Bash does not have (maybe) that capability

you could certainly perform the operation in awk but you'd need to be careful on the order in which files are fed to awk; if you simply feed cat L00? to awk then awk will incur 192 open/close file operations (expensive); if you feed cat L00? | sort to awk you only perform 48 open/close file operations, but whether that's 'faster' than a comparable  paste | while/cat operation will likely depend on the size of the file*_L00? files; I would expect cat to be more efficient than awk (effectively) looping on reading/printing lines; having said that ....

if you explicitly want an awk solution then you should a) add the awk tag, b) state you want an awk solution and c) update the question with your own awk attempt (along with a description of how it does not do what you want)

Assumptions:

must process files based on names in the L00? files
must process files in the same order in which they are listed in the L00? files
we do not know beforehand the names of the files in the L00? files

One idea using a pair of for/while loops:
rm -rf All_file*.file

for ((i=1;i<=4;i++))
do
    while read -r fname
    do
        pfx="${fname%_*}"
        cat "${fname}" >> "All_${pfx}.file"
    done < L00${i}
done


If we know for a fact that all of the 1st line filenames are to be cat'd together, then all of the 2nd line filesnames, etc ...
Use the paste command to match associated files, eg:
$ paste L001 L002 L003 L004 | head -3
file1_L001      file1_L002      file1_L003      file1_L004
file2_L001      file2_L002      file2_L003      file2_L004
file3_L001      file3_L002      file3_L003      file3_L004

We could then feed this into a single while loop, eg:
while read -r flist
do
    read -r f1 _ <<< "${flist}"               # f1 == first file name
    pfx="${f1%_*}"                            # strip off the '_L00?' suffix
    cat "${flist}" > "All_${pfx}.file"
done < <(paste L001 L002 L003 L004)

This 2nd approach is going to be more efficient if simply because we go from 192 (4x48) cat / >> operations down to 48 cat / > operations.

If you've got Bash 4.0 (released in 2009) or later, try this Shellcheck-clean Bash program:
#! /bin/bash -p

readarray -t list1 <L001
readarray -t list2 <L002
readarray -t list3 <L003
readarray -t list4 <L004

for ((i=0; i<48; i++)); do
    cat -- "${list1[i]}" "${list2[i]}" "${list3[i]}" "${list4[i]}" \
        > "ALL_file$((i+1)).file"
done


readarray ((weirdly) aka mapfile) copies each line of its input into a Bash array.  readarray/mapfile was introduced in Bash 4.0.
$((i+1)) expands to the value of the arithmetic expression $i+1.  See ArithmeticExpression - Greg's Wiki.

